# Filtering data with LINQ doesn't seem to compile properly

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

So I have a following method, checking for existance of a post by it's id:

```
public Task<bool> PostExistByIdAsync(string id)
{
    return Task.FromResult(_dbContext.Posts.Any(a => a.Id.Equals(id)));
}
```

The problem I saw is that it compiles into the following query:

```
SELECT "p"."Id", "p"."AccountId", "p"."Post", "p"."Timestamp"
FROM "Posts" AS "p"
```

So instead of using the `WHERE` clause, it rather iterate over hundreds of results to find a valid entity. This is the output log when calling `PostExistByIdAsync("109");`

```
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 1}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 2}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 3}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 4}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 5}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 6}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 7}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 8}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 9}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 10}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 11}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 12}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 13}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 14}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 15}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 16}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 17}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 18}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 19}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 20}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 21}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 22}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 23}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 24}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 25}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 26}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 27}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 28}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 29}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 30}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 31}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 32}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 33}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 34}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 35}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 36}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 37}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 38}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 39}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 40}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 41}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 42}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 43}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 44}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 45}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 46}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 47}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 48}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 49}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 50}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 51}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 52}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 53}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 54}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 55}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 56}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 57}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 58}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 59}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 60}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 61}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 62}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 63}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 64}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 65}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 66}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 67}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 68}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 69}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 70}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 71}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 72}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 73}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 74}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 75}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 76}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 77}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 78}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 79}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 80}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 81}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 82}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 83}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 84}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 85}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 86}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 87}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 88}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 89}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 90}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 91}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 92}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 93}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 94}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 95}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 96}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 97}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 98}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 99}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 100}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 101}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 102}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 103}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 104}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 105}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 106}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 107}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 108}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
    Context 'PostDataModel' started tracking '{Id: 109}' entity with key 'ClientDataStoreDbContext'.
[......]
```

Same happens while using `_dbContext.Posts.Where(...)` instead of `_dbContext.Posts.Any(...)`.

1. Why is that? It would be definitely cheaper to apply a `WHERE`
   clause in the sql query rather than creating hundreds of the
   entities to iterate.
2. Why the Entity Framework doesn't care about the performance at this
       point?

## Edit

`Posts` property in the `_dbContext`:

```
public DbSet<PostDataModel> Posts { get; set; }
```

PostDataModel:

```
public class PostDataModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public AccountDataModel Account { get; set; }

    public string Post { get; set; }

    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `Posts` property of `_dbContext`?

Comment: Is `Posts` an `IEnumerable<Post>` (e.g. a memory pinned table) or an `IQueryable<Post>`?  If it's IEnumerable, the traffic you are seeing is just lazy loading.... and unavoidable.

Comment: Added this into my question. See my edit.

Comment: What EF Core version are you using? Also what if you replace `Equals` with `==`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Version 2.1.1. It's the same with `==`.

Comment: I'm on 2.1.0 and it doesn't seem to happen. It would be strange so simple query to cause client evaluation. Another thing to mention is that I'm using SqlServer and get `EXISTS (…)` SQL as I expect, while you are using SQLite. Not sure if the EFC provider can change the client vs server evaluation.

Comment: @IvanStoev I will verify that. Meanwhile I found an approach to get it to work. Looks like the EF LINQ is different and we need to target `IQueryable` there. For example, using `.AnyAsync(...)` instead of `.Any(...)` works fine. Weird, because there is a `IQueryable` `.Any(...)` implementation as well.

Comment: @Categle did you ever find out what the problem was? Is there any chance that your code was somehow invoking the Enumerable<T> version of Any(), e.g. by passing a Func<T,boo> instead of an Expression<Func<T,bool>> to the method? What you are describing seems to be consistent with that. Otherwise, did you try reporting this as an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/entityframeworkcore/issues/new?

Comment: @divega Yes. It turned out to be targeting the `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>` version of `Any()`. Using `AnyAsync()` instead helped, then after restarting Visual Studio `Any()` could successfully resolve to `IQueryable<T>`, which fixed the issue. I'm not sure, but it could be some Visual Studio derp.

Comment: Thanks for the update. AnyAsync is a custom operator defined by EF Core and AFAIR, we only define the IQueryble<T> version. I have never heard of any issue that could cause overload resolution to misbehave temporarily in that way. If you hit this again, I would suggest you report it as an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues. I will post my theory as an answer, so it can help others.